# How to make global variables?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, visual-studio-2010, c#-4.0

In Windows application development using `C# .NET`, how do you make a global variable or global instance of a class, which can then be directly used by all other windows forms, e.g. form1, form2, etc.

Comment: Question is: do you _want_ to use global variables? If so, what have you tried?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create singleton class so that instace can be created once and used across application

```
public class Global 
{
    private static readonly Global instance = new Global();
    public static Global Instance
    {
        get
        {
            return instance;
        }
    }

    Global()
    {
    }
    public string myproperty
    {
        get;set;
    }
    }
```

Usage:
    Global.Instance.myproperty

Answer (score 2):

You can create a [static](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/98f28cdx%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) class and define a static variable inside it.

All the classes in your project can refer to it using `MyGlobalVariables.GlobalVariable`

```
public static class MyGlobalVariables
{
   public static int GlobalVariable;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a `public static class` which holds the global variables

eg.

```
public static class GlobalValues
{
      public static int UserId{get;set;}
}
```

Read more about [C# Global Variable](http://www.dotnetperls.com/global-variable)

Also I guess you should read about [Classes and Structs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173109%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Make it as a static variable and static class, e.g.

`private static string foo = "this is static";`

`public static class Bar
{}`