# How to carry a value in a class through multiple forms

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a value in my first form of a game which I would like to access on the next 2 forms. This value is saved in a private class. How would I go about doing this? 
All help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: WebForms or WinForms?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new constructor in your target Winform class that takes the value as a parameter. Do the same for the subsequent form.

```
private MyType _value;

public MyForm(MyType myValue) : this()
{
    _value = myValue;
}
```

To show the new form from your original form:

```
var form = new MyForm(someValue);
form.Show(); // or ShowDialog()
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I have 3 Forms, How can this be done to be accessed on the 3rd form?

Comment: Exactly the way I described it.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "twice on one form."  If you want to open two other forms from a form, yes, you can do that.  It might be confusing for the user, though.

Comment: I want to access the name the user entered (in a text box) on the start screen on 3 other forms

Comment: Each form can have its own constructor method, just like the one I described above.  `MyOtherForm(string name);`  `MyThirdForm(string name);`

Comment: I get this error message when trying to access the class - Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Answer (score 0):

Use get/set to define your value:

```
Class Form1
int _x; // value you want to access from other class/form
public int YourNumber;
{
  get
  {
    return this._x;
  }
  set
  {
     this._x= value;
  }
}
```

Now to access/modify from other class for example Form2:

```
Class Form2
Form1 form = new Form1();
form.YourNumber = 5; // and it's changed in Form1 also

int y = form.YourNumber; // and you get it from Form1
```

Answer (score 0):

Use Global Variable concept so that you can access across multiple forms. You can find details from 
[How to make global variables?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20540449/how-to-make-global-variables/20540705#20540705)

Example:
http://dotnetmirror.com/Articles/wpf/116/global-variables-in-wpf-winforms-mvvm